# Update node back to unknown in octomap

Tags: octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When a scan from a sensor is inserted into an octomap the nodes of the octree are updated. Depending on a sensor hit or miss the occupancy probability, initialized at 0.5, changes. According to the default values, the probability of a node being occupied is 0.7 and of a node being free is 0.4. So if a node has been reported as free a number of times it is marked as free. Now I'm interested in lowering the probability of a node being free as time passes by and no measurement has been received. Such that free space becomes unknown again if it has not been seen free for a while. Is this possible and how can this best be done?

**Update:** In reply to the answer of @dornhege: I do assume setting the probability to 0.5, i.e., setting the value/logOdds to 0.0. However I notice that when a node has been updated to occupied, it can not be updated back to unknown. While traversing all leafs of the tree after a scan insertion I do the following:

```
OcTreeNode* node = octoMap_->octree.search(it.getKey());
node->setLogOdds(octomap::logodds(0.5f));
octoMap_->octree.updateInnerOccupancy();
```

When I next check if the node is occupied with

```
octoMap_->octree.isNodeOccupied(node)
```

true is returned and the occupancy is 0.5. How should I deal with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53160/update-node-back-to-unknown-in-octomap/) by [bcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3802/bcoenen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-01-23**:
For general OctoMap questions and discussions (not related to ROS), I would suggest using our new mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/forum/octomap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @dornhege wrote, you will have to do it manually. Once nodes are created in OctoMap they are assumed to never disappear, i.e., they don't go back to unknown. After an update, you could check the updated nodes (or regularly traverse through all) and then [delete](http://octomap.github.com/octomap/doc/classoctomap_1_1OcTreeBaseImpl.html#abc170f9acea68c32ade0fd923f4f8ca8) the ones that have a log-odds of 0 (or close by).

You could also look at OcTreeStamped (since you mention lowering probabilities after timeouts), and how it is used in [collider](http://www.ros.org/wiki/collider). It offers you time stamps of the last update.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure, you can do that, but you'll have to do it manually AFAIK.

I assume, you mean increasing (i.e. towards 0.5). You'd need to iterator over all free cells and update them according to your needs.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1